How to use localization in flutter app retrieved data from API
I don't know how to translate my application using data from the API. I want a way to translate my application that contains data from the API.
I couldn't find the solution; please help me.
Give me code simplify my app.

Have you tried easy_localization?
Maybe the HttpAssetLoader() can do the trick.
